# $E[(X+Y)^2Z^2]\ge E[X^2Z^2]$ when $E[(X+Y)^2]\ge E[X^2]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

Assume that $X,Y,Z$ are three **mean-zero** random variables, where $E[YX]=0$, $E[YZ]=0$, and $E[(X+Y)^2]\ge E[X^2]$. Does it hold that $E[(X+Y)^2Z^2]\ge E[X^2Z^2]$? I know that it holds when $(X,Y,Z)$ follows a multivariate Gaussian distribution, but does it hold for non-Gaussian cases?

Comment: The condition $\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^2] \geq \mathbb{E}[X^2]$ is always true whenever $\mathbb{E}[XY] = 0$. So that isn't really giving any additional information.

Comment: @sudeep5221, thanks, but does the inequality hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X,Y, V$ be independent Rademacher and
$$
Z = \begin{cases}
V & \text{ if } XY = -1\\
0 & \text{ if } XY = 1
\end{cases}
$$
i.e., $Z\in\{-1,0,1\}$, and $Z^2$ is a Bernoulli with parameter $1/2$ (since $V^2=1$). You can check that the conditions are satisfied: $\mathbb{E}[Z]=0$, and $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[YZ]=0$.
Since $X^2=Y^2=1$,
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^2Z^2] - \mathbb{E}[X^2Z^2] = \mathbb{E}[Z^2]+ 2\mathbb{E}[XY Z^2] = \mathbb{E}[(1+2XY)Z^2] 
$$
Now, when $XY > 0$ then $(1+2XY)Z^2=(1+2XY)\cdot 0 = 0$, and when $XY < 0$ then $(1+2XY)Z^2 = 1+2XY = -1$, so $\mathbb{E}[(1+2XY)Z^2] = -1/2$. This shows that
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^2Z^2] < \mathbb{E}[X^2Z^2] 
$$

Comment: But I require Z is mean-zero.

Comment: @Harry should be fixed now.

Comment: If I require $E[XZ]\ne 0$, does the inequality hold? @Clement C.

Comment: @Harry This counterexample doesn't but there may be another one -- not sure. I think the main question should be reverse: *why* do you think it would hold with this requirement? Is there some intuition you are pursuing (or are you trying to add somewhat arbitrary constraints until it holds)?

Comment: I just found that I forgot to mention that $E[XZ]\ne 0$. I believe the inequality doesn't hold for non-Gaussian cases, but I'd like to see a counterexample. Sorry, I am not good at constructing a counterexample. Your solution is much appreciated. @Clement C.

Comment: @Harry replace $V$ by $X$ in the above. Then $\mathbb{E}[XZ] = 1/2$, but the rest should still go through. (Might be worth double-checking.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Clement C.